# Unity Render Texture Gets Rotated When Applied

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on custom portals in unity that use render textures to simulate what the player would see through the other portal. I'm running into the issue where the texture gets rotated when applied, and I'm not sure why it's happening. The object the texture is cast on has no rotation on any axis, and theres nothing in my code that would cause this (as far as I can tell). Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Portal linkedPortal;
    public Camera portalCam;
    public Camera playerCam;
    public PortalScreen portalScreen;
    public MeshRenderer screenRen;

    public Vector3 cameraPos;
    public RenderTexture viewTexture;

    void Awake()
    {
        playerCam = Camera.main;
        portalCam = linkedPortal.GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
        portalScreen = GetComponentInChildren<PortalScreen>();
        screenRen = portalScreen.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        portalCam.transform.position = transform.position - (playerCam.transform.position - linkedPortal.portalScreen.screenPos);
        portalCam.transform.position = new Vector3 (portalCam.transform.position.x, playerCam.transform.position.y, portalCam.transform.position.z);
        portalCam.transform.eulerAngles = playerCam.transform.eulerAngles + new Vector3 (0f, 180f, 0f);

        if (viewTexture == null || viewTexture.width != Screen.width || viewTexture.height != Screen.height)
        {
            if (viewTexture != null)
            {
                viewTexture.Release();
            }

            viewTexture = new RenderTexture (Screen.width, Screen.height, 0);
            portalCam.targetTexture = viewTexture;
            screenRen.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", viewTexture);
        }
    }
}
```